# Input being skipped and outputing garabge values

Tags: c++, terminal

I'm making a simple shopping cart program that will output the cost of items based on the cost and the quantity. 
After compiling, the program ran successfully, however, when I got to item 2, it skipped the input on the item name and went straight to the item cost. Additionally, when I outputted what was available I got a lot of nonsense values instead of the actual cost of the total shopping cart. I tried excluding Item2 entirely but still got garbage values as outputs. This is my code.
ItemToPurchase.cpp

```
#include "ItemToPurchase.h"

ItemToPurchase::ItemToPurchase() {
   string itemName = "none"; 
   int itemPrice = 0; 
   int itemQuantity = 0;
}

string ItemToPurchase::GetName() {
   return itemName; 
}

int ItemToPurchase::GetPrice() {
   return itemPrice; 
}

int ItemToPurchase::GetQuantity() {
   return itemQuantity; 
}

void ItemToPurchase::SetName(const char *itemName) {
   this->itemName = itemName;
}

void ItemToPurchase::SetPrice(int itemPrice) {
   this->itemPrice = itemPrice; 
}

void ItemToPurchase::SetQuantity(int itemQuantity) {
   this->itemQuantity = itemQuantity; 
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ItemToPurchase.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    ItemToPurchase Item1;  
    ItemToPurchase Item2; 
    string item1name; 
    int item1price;
    int item1quantity; 
    string item2name; 
    int item2price; 
    int item2quantity; 

    cout << "Item 1" << endl; 
    cout << "Enter the item name: "; 
    getline(cin, item1name);

    item1name = Item1.GetName(); 
    Item1.SetName(item1name.c_str()); 

    cout << "Enter the item price: ";
    cin >> item1price;

    item1price = Item1.GetPrice(); 
    Item1.SetPrice(item1price);

    cout << "Enter the item quantity: ";
    cin >> item1quantity; 

    item1quantity = Item1.GetQuantity();
    Item1.SetQuantity(item1quantity);

    cout << "Item 2" << endl; 
    cout << "Enter the item name: ";
    getline(cin, item2name); 

    item2name = Item2.GetName();
    Item2.SetName(item2name.c_str()); 

    cout << "Enter the item price: ";
    cin >> item2price; 

    item2price = Item2.GetPrice();
    Item2.SetPrice(item2price); 

    cout << "Enter the item quantity: ";
    cin >> item2quantity; 

    item2quantity = Item2.GetQuantity();
    Item2.SetQuantity(item2quantity);


    cout << "TOTAL COST" << endl; 
    cout << item1name << item1quantity << "@ " << "$" << item1price << "= " << "$" << item1price * item1quantity << endl; 
    cout << item2name << item2quantity << "@ " << "$" << item2price << "= " << "$" << item2price * item2quantity << endl;

    cout << "TOTAL: " << "$" << (item1price * item1quantity) + (item2price * item2quantity) << endl;


    return 0; 

}
```

And this is the output in my terminal

```
PS C:\Users\chine\OneDrive\Documents\LAB 5#1> ./main.exe
Item 1
Enter the item name: Chocolate Chip Cookies    
Enter the item price: 13
Enter the item quantity: 1
Item 2
Enter the item name: Enter the item price: 3 <- Item name was skipped here
Enter the item quantity: 4
TOTAL COST
0@ $4199120= $0
6422268@ $1994867484= $-304621680
TOTAL: $-304621680
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 problems:

**1**: I think you indented to assign some default values to ItemToPurchase's member variables within the constructor. But what you did is to assign it to local variables. To assign it to the object's member variables you should not use the type identifier:

```
ItemToPurchase::ItemToPurchase() {
  itemName = "none"; 
  itemPrice = 0; 
  itemQuantity = 0;
}
```

In general it is a qood practice to use some suffix or prefix to distinguish member variables from other variables: e.g.: `m_itemName` or `itemName_`.

**2**:
This fragment

```
    cout << "Enter the item price: ";
    cin >> item2price; 

    item2price = Item2.GetPrice();
    Item2.SetPrice(item2price);
```

actually has no effect. You never use the value read in from stdin as you overwrite `item2Price` with the object's member (which has no default value) in this statement `item2price = Item2.GetPrice();`. Remove this line (and similar ones in the other fragments) to get it working.

Comment: I cleared the fragments and made the corrections in the ItemToPurchase constructor and I'm getting the values I want in my terminal. However, I'm still unable to input the Item name for item 2. It still skips over into item cost.

Comment: `cin >> item1quantity` leaves a trailing newline in the inputstream which is then read by `getline`. You need to remove the newline from the inputstream for example by using `cin.ignore()` before `getline`.